# Dynamically allocated array in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

Here is a class, which is basically an array of numbers on which I want to perform some operations.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { //constructor
        int * array = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = i*i;
        }
    } //end constructor
    int displayIthElement(int i) {
        return array[i];
    }
}
```

I get: error, identifier "array" is undefined in the displayIthElement function. It's as if the array array stops existing outside of the constructor function, which makes no sense. What is the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this C++? If it is you should add the C++ tag.

Comment: "It's as if the array array stops existing outside of the constructor function, which makes no sense." <- that's what happens when you make a local variable.

Comment: How else can I create the array if it's not in the constructor function? Isn't it the job of the construction function?

Comment: @jazzybazz: Did you even read my response?  Declaration and initialization are two different things.

Answer (score 6):

> It's as if the array array stops existing outside of the constructor function, which makes no sense.

Actually, it's the only behavior that makes any sense at all... this is how the language works.

`array` is a local variable declared and defined in your constructor.  When the constructor exits the pointer variable is destroyed, and you leak the memory it refers to.  Memory allocated with `new` or `new []` *always* requires a corresponding `delete` or `delete []` before its referent goes out of scope.  Always.

`array` should be a member of the class.  You're learning, so it's a good idea to figure out how dynamic memory handling works, but in the future, prefer a safe container (i.e., `std::unique_ptr`, `std::vector`, etc.) which handles allocation and deallocation for you.

```
class foo {
public:
  foo() { 
    array = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      array[i] = i*i;
    }       
  }
private:
  int *array;  // when does this get deallocated?  Look up RAII
};
```

Comment: "always gets a corresponding delete"? I know what you mean, but the wording's a bit confusing. "requires a corrsponding delete" seems less ambiguous. But, if you assign the result of `new` to smart pointers, you don't need delete anyhow...

Comment: @Roddy: I don't think it's ambiguous... anything allocated with `new` gets a `delete` at some point.  The fact that smart pointers do this for you is irrelevant; you still have to understand how they work.  We're obviously dealing with a beginner. I think mentioning the STL types which handle memory for you is a good thing, but beginners should understand how memory management works first and foremost.

Comment: Possibly I'm just in a pedantic frame of mind :-)  We both know what's meant, but the "gets" just confused me on first reading. The important thing is that `new`ed memory doesn't get *automatically* `deleted` when its referent goes out of scope.

Comment: @Roddy: Eh, I see what you're saying.  May as well change it.